# How to get rid of 00:00:00 when converting a timestamp to a date?

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have just started learning SQL, so this is probably a rookie question. I searched the internet, but haven't found the answer.

I have a users database with a "created_at" column. The data stored there is a timestamp, i.e. looks like

```
2014-12-20 07:07:45
```

For my exercise, I only need the date, i.e. the year, the month and the day.

However, when I use

```
SELECT
      DATE(created_at)
FROM users
```

I get

```
2014-12-20 00:00:00
```

How do I get rid of the time and only get the date?

Thank you so much and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: It works as you want when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5648873539f7c0263b28fd0f2ec3449f.

Comment: `date('2014-12-20 07:07:45')` returns `'2014-12-20'`

Comment: Well, it clearly doesn't work in my case and I don't understand why.
I'm doing my exercise in Mode Analytics and it returns date with zeroes for time

Comment: Then it is not SQLite.

Comment: Any ideas what it might be? The first course used SQLite, I assumed the second will use the same, but turns out it doesn't and I have no idea what I'm working with...

Comment: Just check this: `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2014-12-20 07:07:45');` if it works

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: `cast(created_at as date)`?

If you don't know which db is it, you can cast the field to string and substring it.

I guess something like: `substring(cast(created_at as varchar),1,10)`

Comment: Yes, it gives the same answer with zeroes for time

Comment: Could you try to `select version()` to see which db are you using?

Comment: @clementine I've updated my answer - you can hack it and cast it to be string and then `substring` it